# Como pegar os valores de uma tabela?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-datatables

Minha duvida é bem básica:

Tenho uma `table`, preciso armazenar em uma variável todos os valores da linha que foi clicada, estou tentando isso com esse método abaixo mas o resultado é "undefined".

O que pode estar errado no código? Ou como poderia fazer?

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $('#example2').DataTable();

    $('#example2 tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var data = table.row(this).data();
        alert(data[0]);
    });
});

  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example2').DataTable({
        "ajax": 'http://localhost:55959/Cliente/getBydesc?json=""',
        "columns": [
            { "data": "codigo" },
            { "data": "codinterno" },
            { "data": "razao" },
            { "data": "fantasia" },
            { "data": "cnpj" },
            { "data": "ie" },
            { "data": "cep" },
            { "data": "endereco" },
            { "data": "numero" },
            { "data": "complemente" },
            { "data": "bairro" },
            { "data": "cidade" },
            { "data": "uf" },
            { "data": "email" },
            { "data": "fone1" },
            { "data": "fone2" },
            { "data": "fone3" },
            { "data": "datacad" },
            { "data": "proprietario" }
        ],
        "columnDefs": [
             { "targets": [0, 2, 3, 18], "visible": true },
             { "targets": '_all', "visible": false },
             { "targets": [18], "width": "20%" },
             { "targets": [2, 3, 18], 'className': 'mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric' },           
        ],
        "buttons": [
            'copy'
        ]
    });
});
```

html

```
 <table id="example2" class="display" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>codigo</th>
                <th>codinterno</th>
                <th>razao</th>
                <th>fantasia</th>
                <th>cnpj</th>
                <th>ie</th>
                <th>cep</th>
                <th>endereco</th>
                <th>numero</th>
                <th>complemente</th>
                <th>bairro</th>
                <th>cidade</th>
                <th>uf</th>
                <th>email</th>
                <th>fone1</th>
                <th>fone2</th>
                <th>fone3</th>
                <th>datacad</th>
                <th>proprietario</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>          
    </table>
```

Comment: posta o codigo da geração da table também por favor

Comment: Alexandre, editei o post e coloquei os codigo da criação da tabela

Comment: já experimentou colocar um each un nivel acima do seu codigo $('#example2 tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var data = table.row(this).data();
        alert(data[0]);
    });

Comment: fiz como vc disse, mas o alert exibe "undefined". veja o codigo:  $(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#example2').DataTable();

        $('#example2 tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
            var data = table.row(this).data();
            alert(data[0]);
        });
    });

Comment: consegui resolver, ao inves de usar data[0], usei data.codigo, ai deu certinho, obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: posta como resposta da questão então, ja que conseguiu resolver, assim ajuda outras pessoas. :)

Answer (score -1):

Você pode usar `$("tr th").next();` e fazer um loop.

Comment: @DiegoF o comentário saiu em inglês, alguém já notificou?